# Embedding Python 2.7 in Visual-c++ 2013 program

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013

We currently have an application that has Python 2.5 embedded in it, and we build this using Visual Studio 2008.

We are looking to migrate to Visual Studio 2013, and Python 2.7. I believe that the Windows build of Python 2.7 uses an earlier version of Visual Studio (2010?). As such, is it possible to use Visual-Studio 2013, or do we have to use the same version as the python build?

*Added* What I mean by this is that we have the standard windows python install on our system, and our application links against the `python25.lib` library. We are not rebuilding the python  system, just linking against it, and using the standard distribution.